# User login zend framework encryption assistance

Tags: php, zend-framework, encryption, zend-framework2, crypt

I'm implementing login functionality in an existing zend framework 1 application. I've merged zend framework 2 into the app. Here's my question.

I am storing the users password in the database with an encryption of:

```
public static function encryptPassword($password)
{        
    $blockCipher = new BlockCipher(new Mcrypt(array('algo' => 'aes')));
    $blockCipher->setKey(core::config(static::CONFIG_NODE_MCRYPT_KEY));
    $result = $blockCipher->encrypt($password);
    return $result;        
}
```

Now my understanding is when I handle the login, I can essentially pass the supplied password through this method and it should equal to the database-stored credential.

**The issue is it is not doing that at all. I'm getting different results.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Encryption is by its definition decryptable, so in my book you shouldn't store encrypted passwords but hashed! Link to read: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php.
2. So you should do something like: $passwod = hash("sha256",$password . $salt);
   This will give you 64 characters long password...

Good luck